# How to draw multiple images on canvas and save the canvas as png image

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, rendering

Hello I am trying to draw multiple images on a canvas, and after that save it as png using html2canvas and canvas2image.

The problem is that only the last image is drawn and when I download it isn't downloading with the image.

I am using a for loop to iterate through the images and then get the src value and their offset to draw. But I think I am missing something here, because only the last image is rendering, but not saving in the file.

Below what I am using to render the images on the canvas:

```js
$(function() { 
  $("#btnSave").click(function() { 
    html2canvas($("#widget"), {
      onrendered: function(canvas) {
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d"); // returns the 2d context object
        var images = document.getElementsByClassName('simg');
        //Find actual position with parent cotainer

        var offsetsContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('imagesholder')[0].getBoundingClientRect();
        for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
          var img = new Image() //creates a variable for a new image
          var offsets = images[i].getBoundingClientRect();
          var imgTop = offsets.top;
          var imgLeft = offsets.left;
          imageLeft = parseInt(imgLeft) - parseInt(offsetsContainer.left);
          imageTop = parseInt(imgTop) - parseInt(offsetsContainer.top);
          img.src = images[i].src; // specifies the location of the image
          img.onload = function() {
            context.drawImage(img, imageLeft, imageTop);// draws the image at the specified x and y location
          }
        }
        // Convert and download as image 
        theCanvas = canvas;
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);

        // Convert and download as image 
        Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas); 
        $("#img-out").append(canvas);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
body {
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;

}

.dataset {
    float: left;
    vertical-align: top;


}

.widget{
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 14px !important;
    line-height: 20px !important;

    margin: 5px;
    vertical-align: top;
    color: #333;

    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid lightgray;


    border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;


    display: inline-block;
    page-break-after: always;

}

.widget .header p {
   padding: 10px;
   border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
   max-width: 360px;
}

.widget .header .title {
    font-weight: bold;
    vertical-align: middle;
    min-height: 36px;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;

}

.widget .header:hover {
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

.widget .header  .title.selected {
    border-color: cornflowerblue;
    background-color: #EEF;

}

.widget .content {
    padding: 5px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    max-height: 400px;
}

.autolayout {
    display: inline-block;
}

.element {
    width: 360px;
}

.compact .content {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.compact .row {
    display: table-row;
    width: 100%;
}

.compact .cell {
    display: table-cell;
}

.compact .row.selected {
    background-color: #eee;
}



.toolbar {
    display: block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 10px;
}

.toolbar .basis {
    min-width: 100px;
}

.btn {
    /*min-width: 60px;*/
}


.cell.value {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-wrap: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.cell.freq {
    width: 60px;
}

.cell.glyph {
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100px;
}


.element {

}
.element table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

.element td {
    padding: 0px;

}

.element .selectable:hover {
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
}


.element .stat {
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 20px;
    font-weigth: bold;
    color: darkgray;
}



.element .bar {
    height: 18px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
.bar-both {
    background-color: #0a67a3 !important;

}

.bar-fg {
    background-color: #3e97d1 !important;
}

.bar-bg {
    background-color: #ddd !important;
}

.selected .bar-fg {
    background-color: #FC0;
}

.selected .bar-both  {
    background-color:#FA0;
}

tr.selected {
    background-color: #eee;
}

.crosstab .selectable:hover {
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

.crosstab tr.selected {
    background-color: #eee;
}

.crosstab .header p {
    max-width: 600px;
}


.crosstab td {
  padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
  text-align: right;
}

.crosstab td.value {
  min-width: 60px;
  max-width: 240px;
  text-align: left;
}

.crosstab .cell {
    vertical-align: top;
}



.crosstab th.cell {
    max-width: 120px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: normal;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 10px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.crosstab .n {
    color: darkgray;
}
.fieldlist {
}

.constraints {
    min-width:300px;
    padding: 10px;

    border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;


}
.constraints table {
    width: 100%;

}

.sidenote {
  max-width:300px;
  padding: 0 10px 0px 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.headnote {
    max-width: 600px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.info-block {
    /*border: 1px solid lightgrey;*/
    background-color: #eee;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;

    /*box-shadow: 0 0 0 0px #9bc0cf, 0 0 0 3px #e0ebf0;*/
}

.menu-item {
}

.menu-item-value {
    text-align: right;
    float: right;
}

.gradient-blue {
    background: #b8e1fc;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #b8e1fc 0%, #a9d2f3 10%, #90bae4 25%, #90bcea 37%, #90bff0 50%, #6ba8e5 51%, #a2daf5 83%, #bdf3fd 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #b8e1fc), color-stop(10%, #a9d2f3), color-stop(25%, #90bae4), color-stop(37%, #90bcea), color-stop(50%, #90bff0), color-stop(51%, #6ba8e5), color-stop(83%, #a2daf5), color-stop(100%, #bdf3fd)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #b8e1fc 0%, #a9d2f3 10%, #90bae4 25%, #90bcea 37%, #90bff0 50%, #6ba8e5 51%, #a2daf5 83%, #bdf3fd 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #b8e1fc 0%, #a9d2f3 10%, #90bae4 25%, #90bcea 37%, #90bff0 50%, #6ba8e5 51%, #a2daf5 83%, #bdf3fd 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #b8e1fc 0%, #a9d2f3 10%, #90bae4 25%, #90bcea 37%, #90bff0 50%, #6ba8e5 51%, #a2daf5 83%, #bdf3fd 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #b8e1fc 0%, #a9d2f3 10%, #90bae4 25%, #90bcea 37%, #90bff0 50%, #6ba8e5 51%, #a2daf5 83%, #bdf3fd 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#b8e1fc', endColorstr='#bdf3fd', GradientType=0); /* IE6-8 */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/canvas2image@1.0.5/canvas2image.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/releases/download/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>
<div id="widget" class="widget" field="AGE" roundby="20" description="Patient age, in years">
  <div class="header">
    <h3>
      Testing header
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div class="imagesholder">
    <img src="https://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-100-50-2.jpg" class="simg"/>
    <img src="https://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-100-50-8.jpg" class="simg"/>
    <img src="https://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-100-50-3.jpg" class="simg"/>
  </div>
  <div class="element ng-scope">
    <div class="content">
      <table>
        <colgroup>
          <col/>
          <col width="60x"/>
          <col width="100px"/>
        </colgroup>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="cell value">Value</th>
            <th class="cell freq">Freq</th>
            <th class="cell value"></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr class="selectable">
            <td class="cell value"><span tooltip="0 to 19">0 to 19</span></td>
            <td class="cell freq">17.2%</td>
            <td class="cell glyph">
              <span class="bar bar-both" style="width: 17.234468937875754%;"></span>
              <span class="bar bar-fg" style="width: 0%;"></span>
              <span class="bar bar-bg" style="width: 0%;"></span>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="selectable">
            <td class="cell value"><span tooltip="20 to 39">20 to 39</span></td>
            <td class="cell freq">18.0%</td>
            <td class="cell glyph">
              <span class="bar bar-both" style="width: 18.03607214428858%;"></span>
              <span class="bar bar-fg" style="width: 0%;"></span>
              <span class="bar bar-bg" style="width: 0%;"></span>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr data-key="40" class="selectable">
            <td class="cell value"><span tooltip="40 to 59">40 to 59</span></td>
            <td class="cell freq ng-binding">34.3%</td>
            <td class="cell glyph">
              <span class="bar bar-both" style="width: 34.2685370741483%;"></span>
              <span class="bar bar-fg" style="width: 0%;"></span>
              <span class="bar bar-bg" style="width: 0%;"></span>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="selectable">
            <td class="cell value"><span tooltip="60 to 79">60 to 79</span></td>
            <td class="cell freq ng-binding">24.0%</td>
            <td class="cell glyph">
              <span class="bar bar-both" style="width: 24.04809619238477%;"></span>
              <span class="bar bar-fg" style="width: 0%;"></span>
              <span class="bar bar-bg" style="width: 0%;"></span>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr data-key="80" class="selectable">
            <td class="cell value"><span tooltip="80 to 99">80 to 99</span></td>
            <td class="cell freq">6.4%</td>
            <td class="cell glyph">
              <span class="bar bar-both" style="width: 6.4128256513026045%;"></span>
              <span class="bar bar-fg" style="width: 0%;"></span>
              <span class="bar bar-bg" style="width: 0%;"></span>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="stat">Mean</td>
            <td >46.1</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br/>
<input type="button" id="btnSave" value="Save PNG"/>

<div id="img-out"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with your code.

Drawing images onto a canvas is just allowed if the image either resides on the same domain or if the webserver you're retrieving the images from explicity allows it using a special response header (CORS).

To overcome this we can serve the images via a proxy (e.g. https://yacdn.org/serve/) and also set the **crossOrigin** property of the image element to 'anonymous'.

Inside the click handler you're looping over the image elements and call the **saveAsPNG** function right away. At that point the images aren't drawn to the canvas yet! You need to catch the onload event of every image and as soon as the last one finished loading & drawing call saveAsPNG().

One last thing - inside the onload handler you're positioning each image using the variables **imageLeft** and **imageTop**. This means the position of your images will always be the values from the last image in the array. Better make this two individual variables of each image instance itself e.g. img.imageLeft=x.

Here's an example:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#btnSave").click(function() {
    html2canvas($("#widget"), {
      onrendered: function(canvas) {
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d"); // returns the 2d context object
        var images = document.getElementsByClassName('simg');
        //Find actual position with parent cotainer
        var counter = 0;
        var offsetsContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('imagesholder')[0].getBoundingClientRect();
        for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
          var img = new Image() //creates a variable for a new image
          img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
          var offsets = images[i].getBoundingClientRect();
          var imgTop = offsets.top;
          var imgLeft = offsets.left;
          imageLeft = parseInt(imgLeft) - parseInt(offsetsContainer.left);
          imageTop = parseInt(imgTop) - parseInt(offsetsContainer.top);
          img.imageLeft = imageLeft;
          img.imageTop = imageTop;
          // specifies the location of the image

          img.onload = function(e) {
            context.drawImage(e.target, e.target.imageLeft, e.target.imageTop); // draws the image at the specified x and y location
            counter++;
            if (counter == images.length) {
              Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas);
            }
          }
          img.src = images[i].src;

        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
}

.dataset {
  float: left;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.widget {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 14px !important;
  line-height: 20px !important;
  margin: 5px;
  vertical-align: top;
  color: #333;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  page-break-after: always;
}

.widget .header p {
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
  max-width: 360px;
}

.widget .header .title {
  font-weight: bold;
  vertical-align: middle;
  min-height: 36px;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
}

.widget .header:hover {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

.widget .header .title.selected {
  border-color: cornflowerblue;
  background-color: #EEF;
}

.widget .content {
  padding: 5px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 400px;
}

.autolayout {
  display: inline-block;
}

.element {
  width: 360px;
}

.compact .content {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.compact .row {
  display: table-row;
  width: 100%;
}

.compact .cell {
  display: table-cell;
}

.compact .row.selected {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.toolbar {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 10px;
}

.toolbar .basis {
  min-width: 100px;
}

.btn {
  /*min-width: 60px;*/
}

.cell.value {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-wrap: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.cell.freq {
  width: 60px;
}

.cell.glyph {
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100px;
}

.element {}

.element table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.element td {
  padding: 0px;
}

.element .selectable:hover {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

.element .stat {
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 20px;
  font-weigth: bold;
  color: darkgray;
}

.element .bar {
  height: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.bar-both {
  background-color: #0a67a3 !important;
}

.bar-fg {
  background-color: #3e97d1 !important;
}

.bar-bg {
  background-color: #ddd !important;
}

.selected .bar-fg {
  background-color: #FC0;
}

.selected .bar-both {
  background-color: #FA0;
}

tr.selected {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.crosstab .selectable:hover {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

.crosstab tr.selected {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.crosstab .header p {
  max-width: 600px;
}

.crosstab td {
  padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
  text-align: right;
}

.crosstab td.value {
  min-width: 60px;
  max-width: 240px;
  text-align: left;
}

.crosstab .cell {
  vertical-align: top;
}

.crosstab th.cell {
  max-width: 120px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: normal;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.crosstab .n {
  color: darkgray;
}

.fieldlist {}

.constraints {
  min-width: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

.constraints table {
  width: 100%;
}

.sidenote {
  max-width: 300px;
  padding: 0 10px 0px 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.headnote {
  max-width: 600px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.info-block {
  /*border: 1px solid lightgrey;*/
  background-color: #eee;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  /*box-shadow: 0 0 0 0px #9bc0cf, 0 0 0 3px #e0ebf0;*/
}

.menu-item {}

.menu-item-value {
  text-align: right;
  float: right;
}

.gradient-blue {
  background: #b8e1fc;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #b8e1fc 0%, #a9d2f3 10%, #90bae4 25%, #90bcea 37%, #90bff0 50%, #6ba8e5 51%, #a2daf5 83%, #bdf3fd 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #b8e1fc), color-stop(10%, #a9d2f3), color-stop(25%, #90bae4), color-stop(37%, #90bcea), color-stop(50%, #90bff0), color-stop(51%, #6ba8e5), color-stop(83%, #a2daf5), color-stop(100%, #bdf3fd));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #b8e1fc 0%, #a9d2f3 10%, #90bae4 25%, #90bcea 37%, #90bff0 50%, #6ba8e5 51%, #a2daf5 83%, #bdf3fd 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #b8e1fc 0%, #a9d2f3 10%, #90bae4 25%, #90bcea 37%, #90bff0 50%, #6ba8e5 51%, #a2daf5 83%, #bdf3fd 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #b8e1fc 0%, #a9d2f3 10%, #90bae4 25%, #90bcea 37%, #90bff0 50%, #6ba8e5 51%, #a2daf5 83%, #bdf3fd 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #b8e1fc 0%, #a9d2f3 10%, #90bae4 25%, #90bcea 37%, #90bff0 50%, #6ba8e5 51%, #a2daf5 83%, #bdf3fd 100%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#b8e1fc', endColorstr='#bdf3fd', GradientType=0);
  /* IE6-8 */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/canvas2image@1.0.5/canvas2image.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/releases/download/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>
<div id="widget" class="widget" field="AGE" roundby="20" description="Patient age, in years">
  <div class="header">
    <h3>
      Testing header
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div class="imagesholder">
    <img src="https://yacdn.org/serve/https://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-100-50-2.jpg" class="simg" />
    <img src="https://yacdn.org/serve/https://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-100-50-8.jpg" class="simg" />
    <img src="https://yacdn.org/serve/https://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-100-50-3.jpg" class="simg" />
  </div>
  <div class="element ng-scope">
    <div class="content">
      <table>
        <colgroup>
          <col/>
          <col width="60x" />
          <col width="100px" />
        </colgroup>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="cell value">Value</th>
            <th class="cell freq">Freq</th>
            <th class="cell value"></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr class="selectable">
            <td class="cell value"><span tooltip="0 to 19">0 to 19</span></td>
            <td class="cell freq">17.2%</td>
            <td class="cell glyph">
              <span class="bar bar-both" style="width: 17.234468937875754%;"></span>
              <span class="bar bar-fg" style="width: 0%;"></span>
              <span class="bar bar-bg" style="width: 0%;"></span>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="selectable">
            <td class="cell value"><span tooltip="20 to 39">20 to 39</span></td>
            <td class="cell freq">18.0%</td>
            <td class="cell glyph">
              <span class="bar bar-both" style="width: 18.03607214428858%;"></span>
              <span class="bar bar-fg" style="width: 0%;"></span>
              <span class="bar bar-bg" style="width: 0%;"></span>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr data-key="40" class="selectable">
            <td class="cell value"><span tooltip="40 to 59">40 to 59</span></td>
            <td class="cell freq ng-binding">34.3%</td>
            <td class="cell glyph">
              <span class="bar bar-both" style="width: 34.2685370741483%;"></span>
              <span class="bar bar-fg" style="width: 0%;"></span>
              <span class="bar bar-bg" style="width: 0%;"></span>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="selectable">
            <td class="cell value"><span tooltip="60 to 79">60 to 79</span></td>
            <td class="cell freq ng-binding">24.0%</td>
            <td class="cell glyph">
              <span class="bar bar-both" style="width: 24.04809619238477%;"></span>
              <span class="bar bar-fg" style="width: 0%;"></span>
              <span class="bar bar-bg" style="width: 0%;"></span>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr data-key="80" class="selectable">
            <td class="cell value"><span tooltip="80 to 99">80 to 99</span></td>
            <td class="cell freq">6.4%</td>
            <td class="cell glyph">
              <span class="bar bar-both" style="width: 6.4128256513026045%;"></span>
              <span class="bar bar-fg" style="width: 0%;"></span>
              <span class="bar bar-bg" style="width: 0%;"></span>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="stat">Mean</td>
            <td>46.1</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br/>
<input type="button" id="btnSave" value="Save PNG" />

<div id="img-out"></div>
```

Comment: Hey thank you for your tips, Yeah I will be using images from the same domain. I tried your example and it almost worked, it rendered the 3rd image in the place of the 1st and 2nd.

Comment: Oh sorry - I've missed that. Inside the onload handler  `context.drawImage(img` needs to be replaced by `context.drawImage(e.target` of course. I've fixed the example above.